# Need to make less padding

Tags: highcharts, padding

Any idea how to make the chart padding smaller?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yep - set the chart's margin to 0:

```
chart: {
  plotBackgroundColor: null,
  plotBorderWidth: null,
  plotShadow: false,
  margin: 0 // <---- change this number
}
```

[**(Live demo here)**](http://livecoding.io/5303254)

Answer (score 0):

You can also set spacing value

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacingRight
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.spacingLeft

To control size of pie chart you can use: 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.size